# How to set one bit of a column in every record using Doctrine 1.2?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I'm trying to build this SQL query:

```
update shop_product set flags=flags^(flags&1024);
```

Using Doctrine 1.2.

I have tried these methods:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('Model_ShopProduct p')
    ->set('p.flags', 'p.flags^(p.flags&' . $flag);
```

also:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('Model_ShopProduct p')
    ->set('p.flags', new Doctrine_Expression('p.flags^(p.flags&?'), $flag);
```

And many similar variations with no success. Please help mi with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way to achieve this is to salvage database connection from `Doctrine` and perfrom raw sql query on it, something like

```
$connection = Doctrine_Manager::getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();
//connection is an ordinary PDO object
$connection->query("update shop_product set flags=flags^(flags&1024);");
```

If you are not familiar with PDO, here is [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) on `PDO::query`.